# Writing to a text file from another text file line by line in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to write to a the text file *fileout* a line at a time from another file, *file_in1*, which is defined globally. I'm getting errors from the code bellow and I don't know why, If someone could figure out why that'd be great. Thanks!

```
void output() 
{
    FILE *fileout;
    char line[40];

    file_in1 = fopen(filename1, "r");

    printf("Please enter the name of the output file: ");
    scanf("%s", filename); //Reads filename

    fileout = fopen(filename, "w");

    if (fileout == NULL) {
        printf("(Ensure the file is located in the project \n file folder and has the .txt extension) \n");
        output();
    }

    while (fgets(line, 90, file_in1) != NULL) //Looks through characters until end of the file
    {
        fputs(line, fileout);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full and exact error?

Comment: is this a type `fgets(line, 90, file_in1)`? because you declare `char line[40]`.

Comment: It gets stuck in a loop, the program appears to take no notice of the !=NULL

Comment: You check for `fileout` why don't you check for `file_in1`, it has greater chance to be `NULL`.

Comment: Because file_in1 is checked in a different function

Comment: What function? you open `file_in1` in a different function?

Comment: file_in1 is opened /right here/, so cannot be checked in a different function. Also message in printf before recursive output() suggests that file should be located somewhere, but shouldn't that be file_in1 and not fileout? file_in1 is leaking nonetheless. (and everything breaks after output() returns).

Comment: @user3125367 `file_in1 is leaking nonetheless` and so is `fileout`.

Comment: @iharob Not sure, it is NULL then. Entire thing is a great mess anyway, probably must close this question and split (or just close).

Comment: Even if `file_in1` was fine, when the recursion returns, it will then try to write on a `fileout` which is `NULL`.

Comment: file_in1 is opened before in a separate function, error checked until the filename entered is acceptable, used, closed, then re-opened in this function.

Comment: @JL9: It should be declared as `FILE *` in this function too though. Unless it's a global variable.

Comment: Why's that? It's declared globally.

Comment: @JL9: Pointed that out already :) That's okay then. Problem with recursion and `fileout` remains though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare

```
char line[40];
```

but later do

```
               //   v--- 90?
while (fgets(line, 90, file_in1) != NULL)
```

line cannot hold 90 characters. Either make `line` larger or read fewer characters.

Comment: This might be the error, but if there are newlines in the text before the `40` characters, then it's not.

Comment: Or try the sizeof(line) operator: `fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_in1)` . thanks for the correction @iharob +1

Comment: @JL9, don't forget to accept this answer, so we don't come back to try answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

the following code

1. compiles cleanly
2. does proper error checking
3. properly reads in the output file name
4. does not cause undefined behaviour (leading to a seg fault event)
   I.E. it limits the number of characters read by fgets()

-

```
void output() 
{
    FILE *fileout;
    char line[40];

    //file_in1 = fopen(filename1, "r"); // <-- always check results
    if( NULL == (file_in1 = fopen(filename1, "r") ) )
    { // fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for input file" ); // writes failure details to stderr
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful for input file

    printf("Please enter the name of the output file: ");
    //scanf("%s", filename); //Reads filename // <-- always check return code
                                              //     and allow for leaidng white space skipping
    if( 1 != scanf( " %s", filename) )
    { // scanf failed
        perror( "scanf failed for output file name" ); // writes failure details to stderr
    }

    // implied else, scanf for output file name successful

    //fileout = fopen(filename, "w");
    //if (fileout == NULL) // <-- always place the literal on the left to enable compiler to catch certain syntax errors
    if( NULL == (fileout = fopen(filename, "w")))
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for output file" ); // writes failure details to stderr
        printf("(Ensure the file is located in the project \n file folder and has the .txt extension) \n");
        // output(); <-- the program failed, do not continue  and certainly not recursively
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful for output file

    //while (fgets(line, 90, file_in1) != NULL) //Looks through characters until end of the file
                                                // <-- line is only defined as 40 characters
    while( NULL != fgets(line, sizeof(line), file_in1))
    {
        fputs(line, fileout);
    }
} // end function: output
```